# Formulation of a problem as semidefinite programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I would appreciate some help with this problem:

$R$ is a positive semidefinite matrix $\in{R}^{n\times n}$, $A \in{R}^{n\times m}$.

I need to formulate this optimization problem as semidefinite programming:

maximize $tr\left(({{A}^{T}{R}^{-1}A)}^{-1}\right)$

subject to $\|{r}_i-{c}_i\| \leq{\rho}_i$,

where ${c}_i$ and ${\rho}_i$ are given vectors and scalars, respectively, and ${r}_i$ =
$\begin{bmatrix} {R}_{1i}\\{R}_{2i} \\.\\.\\.\\ {R}_{ii}  \end{bmatrix}$, $i = 1,...,n$.

I got a hint that it is useful to use Schur complement, but I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Are you assuming the existence of $R^{-1}$? Also, is the type of  norm given?

Comment: Yes. Assumed L2 norm.

Comment: The Schur complement hint could be referring to an "epigraph"-type substitution $Y = A^T R^{-1} A$, where the constraint $Y \succeq A^T R^{-1} A$ can be converted using the Schur complement. However, $tr(Y^{-1})$ is convex, not concave, over $\mathbf{S}_n^{++}$. Are you sure you are maximizing the objective?

Comment: I agree completely with your reasoning. And, I am completely sure that the goal is to maximize the objective (our assistant gave us the problem like this). That is why the problem puzzles me. No one in our class has managed to formulate the problem as SDP. P.S. Thanks for your involvement so far. :-)

Comment: The constraints look like max distance constraints for Euclidean distance matricies/Gram matricies. I believe there are SDP relaxations for these constraints, not sure about equivalent reformulations though.